# req.headers.range cant find if call from android devices?

Tags: node.js, http-headers, streaming, audio-streaming

I try to make streaming of audio file in nodeJS. But If i call from browser than it still work good but if call from any devices than it's not work because of range not found.

```
//If call from Browser req.headers output like
{ host: 'localhost:7060',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'user-agent': 'stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.4.4)',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
   range: 'bytes=1-696319' }

//If call from devices
{ host: 'localhost',
 'user-agent': 'stagefright/1.1 (Linux;Android 2.3.6)' }
```

only that output occurs i can't found any ranges here what can i do for that?

app.js file

```
var fs = require('fs'),
queryString = require('querystring');

var query, URI;

exports.streamMP3 = function(req, res){
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
res.header("crossDomain","true");
res.header("Range","bytes=1-999");
//console.log(req);
try{
    query = URI = null;
    //console.log("METHOD:", req.method);
    if(req.method=='POST') {
        query =  req.body;
    }else{
        URI = decodeURIComponent(req.url);
        if (req.url.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
            query = queryString.parse(req.url.replace(/^.*\?/, ''));
        }
    }
    console.log("QUERY:", query);

    var audio_file_path = null;
    var audio_file_id = null;
    if(query && query.id){
        audio_file_id = query.id;
        audio_file_path = './mp3/'+audio_file_id+'.mp3';
    }else{
        audio_file_path = './mp3/tmp.mp3';
    }

    fs.readFile(audio_file_path, "binary", function(err, file) {

        var header = {};
        // add content type to header
        //req.headers.range = 'bytes=1-696319';

        console.log(req.headers);
        //TODO: any more clean solution ?
        if(typeof req.headers.range != 'undefined'){
            // browser wants chunged transmission
            var range = req.headers.range;
            var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
            var partialstart = parts[0]; 
            var partialend = parts[1]; 

            var total = file.length; 

            var start = parseInt(partialstart,10); 
            var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend,10) : total-1;

            var diff = end - start;
            var value = parseInt((partialend*20)/100,10);
            if(diff > value){
                end = start + value;
            }
            var chunksize = (end-start)-10000; 

            console.log(start , end);
            //var end = parseInt((partialend*20)/100, 10);
            header["Content-Range"] = "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + (total);
            header["Accept-Ranges"] = "bytes";
            header["Content-Length"]= chunksize;
            header['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked';
            header["Connection"] = "close";
            //console.log(start, end);

            res.writeHead(206, header); 
            // yeah I dont know why i have to append the '0'
            // but chrome wont work unless i do
            //res.end(file.slice(start, chunksize), "binary"); 
            res.write(file.slice(start, end)+'0', "binary");
        }else{
            console.log("Unchunked");
            // reply to normal un-chunked request
            res.writeHead(200, header );
            res.write(file, "binary");
        }
        res.end();
    });
}catch(e){
    console.log("TRY ERROR:", e);
    res.end();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all clients will request a specific range.  In fact, the majority do not.  Your code should be able to handle these requests by simply returning the entire resource from byte 0 to the end.